# UDP Flooding on physical server due to couchdb

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

**Current setup:** Installed couchdb on server and is connected to a gwt application hosted on tomcat. Rhel 6 is the operating system and its firewall is turned off. The server is connected to a cyberoam (physical) firewall.

**Problem:** As soon as the apache Tomcat server services are turned on, the cpu usage of the cyberoam firewall reaches to 100% at regular intervals and thus the firewall stops operating till that time. Upon research it reveals that the UDP flooding caused by the server is the reason for this problem. For this when we connected our application with MySQl, it was running fine and the firewall cpu didn't show any spikes but when it was connected to couchdb and tomcat was turned ON, the firewall cpu usage again showed 100% spike at certain interwal due to UDP flooding.

Kindly suggest how to recuperate from this problem. Any ports to be enabled or disabled through firewall (physical)?

Comment: Any idea what the Java server is doing at the time? Have you tried taking thread dumps to see what is going on?

Comment: After lots of research I came across the problem that the ISP operator IP pool was creating the problem.If I started the services with another IP pool then there was no problem. BUt the question is why was that IP pool causing the UDP flooding?

Answer (score 0):

Just add bypass rule for particular IP and check once.

Comment: I think you should give more guidance. This reads like a mediocre comment, not like a true answer answering the question!